# Show that if $C_1$ and $C_2$ are two distinct components of a space X, then $C_1\cap C_2$ = $\emptyset$

Tags: general-topology

This is part of my proof:Suppose $C_1 \cap C_2\neq \emptyset$,then there exists some element $x$ in $C_1 \cap C_2$.Since $C_1$ and $C_2$ are connected and closed,then......

Can someone continue the proof? I think the last step would be showing some contradiction

Answer (score 1):

$C_1 \cup C_2$ is also connected, contradicting the maximality of components (a component is a maximimally connected subset; any larger subset is no longer connected).

Comment: This is what I tried.But I'm wondering why $ C_1 \cup C_2$ is also connected?

Comment: @XYC because they intersect. Should have been a standard theorem: two intersecting connected sets have a connected union.